# If where and or clause in Sql searching

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have build a query to search on text using n_make and n_month using if, where and or clause

However - unsure why is n_month not getting executed, search only happening for text if its in n_make and not in n_month

I want a search to display output if its shown in either n_make or n_month

```
    // Filter by search in title
    $search = $this->getState('filter.search');

    if (!empty($search))
    {
        if (stripos($search, 'id:') === 0)
        {
            $query->where('a.id = ' . (int) substr($search, 3));
        }
        else
        {
            $search = $db->Quote('%' . $db->escape($search, true) . '%');
            $query->where('( a.n_make LIKE ' . $search . ' )')
            or
            $query->where('( a.n_month LIKE ' . $search . ' )')
            ;
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    else
    {
        $search = $db->Quote('%' . $db->escape($search, true) . '%');
        $query->where('( a.n_make LIKE' . $search . ') OR ( a.n_month LIKE' . $search . ')');
    }
```